# Rでシグマ計算をcbindしたいです

Tags: r

$$\sum_{n=1}^k \sin 2n\pi p $$
をk=1から4までのパターンでcbindしたい（以下の様な感じ）のですが、どのようにプログラムすればよいでしょうか？
ちなみにこの文の外にfor文があるのでcycleは上書きになっても構いません。

```
cycle<-cbind(sin(2*pi*p))
cycle<-cbind(sin(2*pi*p),sin(4*pi*p))
cycle<-cbind(sin(2*pi*p),sin(4*pi*p),sin(6*pi*p))
cycle<-cbind(sin(2*pi*p),sin(4*pi*p),sin(6*pi*p),sin(8*pi*p))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

p の値は適当ですが、以下の様になりますでしょうか。

```
p <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)

cycle <- NULL
for (k in 1:4) {
  c <- NULL
  for (n in 1:k) {
    c <- cbind(c, sin(2*n*pi*p))
  }
  cycle <- cbind(cycle, c)
}
```

**追記**

コメントの内容から考えますと、以下の様になるのでしょうか？

```
cycle <- NULL
for (k in 1:4) {
  cycle <- cbind(cycle, sin(2*k*pi*p))
}
```

Comment: for文を2重にして2つ目の変数をkにしている意味を詳しく知りたいです。
また、c <- cbind(c, sin(2*n*pi*p))ではなく
c <- cbind(sin(2*n*pi*p))のような気がするのですが気のせいでしょうか？

Comment: @user87562 `cbind((n=1の結果),(n=1,2の結果),(n=1,2,3の結果),(n=1,2,3,4の結果))` だと捉えていましたが、どうやら違っていた様ですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。追記のプログラムが望んだ結果でした。